# Changing the files in a folder from JPG to JPEG

Tags: python

How can I permanently change the files in a folder from JPG to JPEG using a script.

Here is my code, but it's not producing any results:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".JPG"):
      base = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
      os.rename(file, base + '.jpeg')
```

Comment: What does your attempt to debug this code tell you?

Comment: This would be easier to do using the Unix `rename` command.

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns filenames without the directory prefix. You need to join the filenames with the prefix when calling `os.rename()`.

Comment: You could also simplify by using `glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.JPG'))`

Comment: That will return the full pathnames, and you don't need to check `file.endswith()` yourself.

Comment: what OS are you using?? to have a cross-platform it's better to use `os.replace` [replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can using opencv for this task:
(Note: in this code you must set '/' at the end of path variable)

```
import os
import cv2

path = "./images/"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".JPG"):
        img = cv2.imread(path+str(file))
        cv2.imwrite(path+file[0:-4]+".jpeg", img)
        os.remove(path+file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os
path = 'imgaegs/*JPG'
for file in glob.glob(path):
    new_file = file.replace('.JPG', '.jpeg')
    os.rename(file, new_file)
```